# Labeling overlapping features while avoiding collinear labels

Tags: arcmap, labeling, overlapping-features

I'm using ArcMap 10.6.0 and I've activated label overlapping features in my class. However, the labels are unreadable because they are also overlapping. I've tried placing offset, but it doesn't fix the issue because labels scatter too much and it becomes hard to identify what values belong to their points.

[image: This is the issue that i'm having]

So, what settings would give me readable labels on overlapping features? I would like both of them to be centered. This is the desired result.

[image: This is what i'm looking for]

Comment: If the features are in the same layer then you might use label classes to define different types and put them in different positions; if they are in different layers then set the different positions.  In Layer Properties - Labels - Placement Properties you can try the position options to get a location for each class/layer or use the user defined option for different ones.  You might also try using the Maplex labeling engine with the best setting.  Lastly, convert labels to annotation and manually place each in an edit session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by toggling on "Reduce Font Size" and then setting lower limit to 2 and step to 1.